# Setting footer bottom of page using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

Hi I am trying to stick the footer the bottom of the page even when my page is thin on content.

I have tried to use below CSS code but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

**CSS**

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>  
  </head>
  <body>     
    <aside class="left-panel">        
    </aside>
    <section class="content">
      <header class="top-head container-fluid">
      </header>
      <!-- Header Ends -->      
      <div class="warper container-fluid">  
        <div class="page-header"><h1>Blank Template <small>Start new page with this</small></h1></div>                             
        <!-- Work Here --> 
      </div>
      <!-- Warper Ends Here (working area) -->
      <footer class="container-fluid footer">
        Copyright &copy; 2014 <a href="#" target="_blank">test</a>
        <a href="#" class="pull-right scrollToTop"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <!-- Content Block Ends Here (right box)--> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Thin on content` mean when page display small data, the footer display at the `end of page` and have more data need to scroll down to see it? Or footer always in `end of current screen`?

Comment: Thin on content mean when page display small data, the footer display at the end of page and have more data need to scroll down to see it? no the footer dose not stick into end of the page when i have small data on the page

Comment: You mean footer always come after data? When your page have small data, footer is show on center of screen (assume that)?

Comment: No it shown in the bottom of the page but there is empty space after the footer

Comment: Have you tried removing the footer from the <section> element and making it the last element in the body? Also, I see you have a "margin-bottom:60px;" for your body. That would cause an empty space at the bottom of your page... If make the footer the last element in Body then you wont need the margin...

Comment: It's seems to work for me.. http://jsbin.com/rehuxi/edit?html,css,output